# showonlyrefs and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, amsmath, cleveref, mathtools

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`autonum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum)

I know that `cleveref` is not compatible with `showonlyrefs` as it says in the `cleveref` manual. But I have a book-length document that depends on `showonlyrefs` and I would like to start using `cref` without having to go back and add a `\notag` to each of the equations that I do not want to assign a number to.

Is there a known hack or an easy way to use `cref`? I have recently begun to appreciate the power of `cleveref` and would like to use it without going back and changing each and every one of my equations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [autonum package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/autonum) for that, as it is compatible with `cref` (but mind the package loading order as described in the manual). In its current version it only supports the equation environment, but I am working on supporting other amsmath environments, too.

**Update**
In its new version 0.2, multi-line equations are supported, so using align should not be a problem (just uploaded, so it might take some time to appear on all mirrors).

Comment: Thanks! But I use the align environment to typeset math by default, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not working on that project at the moment, but I will be sure to report back once I start using it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi MMM, I finally got around to trying out the `autonum` package, but can't see to get it to work. Here is a minimal example which compiles with "undefined references":

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, cleveref}

\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eq:eq1}

a = b+c

\end{align}

Refer to equation \cref{eq:eq1}.

\end{document}

Comment: @FgNu, I did not implement support for special characters in label names. If you change the label name `eq:eq1` into `eqFirst`, everything should work.

Comment: For the records: Special characters [are supported](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63552/7323) in more recent versions.