# Shorthand for numbered equation environment

Tags: equations

Is there any shorthand for numbered equation environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a package, which only numbers the referenced equations, there is no need for a distinction between a numbered and an unnumbered equation. This is possible with [mathtools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4729/7323). If you always want to use the normal equation shorthand (like `\[a + b = c\]`), you can use the [autonum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58231/7323) package.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a new command to start the environment and other to finish it, for example, `\def\beq{\begin{equation}}`.

Comment: You could also use `\let\beq\equation` and `\let\eeq\endequation`.

Comment: Werner's suggestion breaks equation numbering.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a lot of custom abbreviations is not good for the readability of your source code. Instead you should use a good editor which helps you with these kind of things.
For example if you are a `vim` user, you can take a look at [`vim-latex`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/), sometimes also called `LaTeX-Suite`. It is a great tool for writing `LaTeX` code and in particular, you just need to type in *EEQ* and it will immediatly replace it with

```
\begin{equation}

\end{equation}<++>
```

place the cursor inside of the environment and allow you to jump to the <++> marker after the environment with *Ctrl+J*.

I found this very comfortable. Of course for some other editors there are probably similar features.

Comment: Thanks, I completely agree with you, however I though when there is a shorthand for number-less equation there should be one for numbers equation, but it seems that it is not true!