# Macro saving a value for next run

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

I need a macro, which saves a string (like the content of a label) to the aux file. During the next run, there should be a macro checking, if that string has been set in the last run or not.

My solution so far presented as an example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\csxdefaux#1{%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \expandafter\string\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname{}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \ifcsdef{setValue}{value set}{value \emph{not} set}
    \csxdefaux{setValue}

    \ifcsdef{strange:value}{strange value set}{strange value \emph{not} set}
    \csxdefaux{strange:value}
\end{document}
```

This results (after multiple compilations) in:
[image]

So although the pair of `\csxdefaux` and `\ifcsdef` macros obviously works for normal strings, it fails for strings with special characters.

What would be a good way to achieve the same as with my solution but supporting a wide range of special characters like colons, digits, umlauts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with `\ifcsdef`, as it is testing correctly and giving the correct answer. To see why, we need to look at the `.aux` file. With your definition, the `.aux` file reads

```
\relax 
\xdef\setValue{}
\xdef\strange:value{}
```

which is then read back by LaTeX to defined `\setValue` (as required), and `\strange` as a delimited macro (wrong). The latter happens as `:` is an 'other' character at this point, and the tokenization you had before is lost when you write something to a file.

What you therefore need is the `\csname ...\endcsname` construct inside the `.aux` file. One working definition is

```
\def\csxdefaux#1{%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\gdef
          \string\csname\string\detokenize{#1}\string\endcsname{}%
    }%
}
```

or using the `etoolbox` wrapper

```
\def\csxdefaux#1{%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \csgdef{\detokenize{#1}}{}%
    }%
}
```

I've detokenized `#1` when it's read back in case something like `babel` has made anything active. (I'm not sure why you have `\xdef`, so went with `\gdef` instead.)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks very much. The `\xdef` is not needed in this simple example, it was a relic of a more complex use case.