# Special Characters and autonum

Tags: autonum

I tried to get special characters with the package `autonum` to work and installed the new version according to
[cleveref, autonum and labeling only referenced equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62604/cleveref-autonum-and-labeling-only-referenced-equations).

I downloaded and copied the files with admin rights to the my MiKTeX 2.9 folder (running on Win 7) but it is still not working.

Any idea on how to fix it?

The used minimal example is this one and it doesn't reference correctly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eq:a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
c = d \label{eq:b}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e = f \label{eq:c}
\end{equation}

See \cref{eq:b}.
\end{document}
```

Best regards

Comment: Testing this, I find the functionality is broken even with the simple case of `autonum` alone with the current release (0.3.5). That makes this a dupe of the earlier question: I'll ping the package author there.