# automatic numbering of labeled equations

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, cleveref, mathtools, autonum

Since `autonum` doesn't play nicely with `cleveref` (nor does the `mathtools` automatic numbering option work for me), I'm looking for a simpler solution.  I'd like equations to be numbered automatically if they have a label in them and not otherwise.  How do I accomplish this?

See [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264399/autonum-and-cleveref-conflict#264399) to see what the problem is with `autonum` and `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{multline} \label{eq:one} % must have a number
 z=a+b+c+d+e+f+g\\
 + h+i+j+k+\ell+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y.
 \end{multline}







 \begin{multline} % must not have a number
 z=a+b+c+d+e+f+g\\
 + h+i+j+k+\ell+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y.
 \end{multline}




\begin{gather} \label{eq:two} % must have a number
 x=y 
\end{gather}

\begin{gather} % must not have a number
 x=y
 \end{gather}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the concept of the exclusive numbering of labeled equations. The purpose of the numbers is to identify an equation easily. The numbers are not for the writer of a paper, but for the reader, who can then reference equations, discuss them with others or the author, ... If equations do not have numbers, then they are either too unimportant and can be removed saving time for writing and reading. Or the missing numbers are an annoyance for the readers. (Or it is a write-only document?)

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  I find redundant equation numbers distracting, plus in my two disciplines, it is common to number only equations that are referenced.

Comment: @JPi: out of curiosity, what are your disciplines?

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the purpose of `autonum`. What determines whether an equation is numbered is not whether it has a `\label{}`, but whether it is referenced at any point, in other words - whether the document contains a `\ref{}` referring to that equation or not.
The `\cref{}` command is also supported, if `cleveref` is loaded.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref,autonum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}\label{eq:a}
 z=a+b+c+d+e+f+g\\
 + h+i+j+k+\ell+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y.
\end{multline}
\begin{multline}\label{eq:b}
 z=a+b+c+d+e+f+g\\
 + h+i+j+k+\ell+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y.
\end{multline}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:c}
 x=y
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:d}
 x=y
\end{gather}
We reference the first \verb|multline| environment, but not the second,
  and the second \verb|gather| environment, but not the first.
Hence. only \cref{eq:a} and \cref{eq:d} will be numbered,
  even though all equations are labelled.
\end{document}
```

[image: only referenced equations are numbered]

If you don't want an equation numbered and know you'll never refer to it, you may just as soon use the starred form of the environment. The `autonum` package is intended specifically to avoid the need to alter the equation itself based on whether it is ever referred to. If it depended on the addition or deletion of a `\label{}`, the package would lose its point since adding or deleting a star is at least as easy and, arguably, easier.

Comment: No, I did not misunderstand.  I've given up on `autonum` since it's way too fussy about other packages and want a work around.

Comment: @JPi But do you want something which does the job it is supposed to do? Or do you want something which works in the way you explain in your question? Because those are quite different: `autonum` would not label ***any*** of the equations in your MWE because none of them are ever referenced. Yet your comments there indicate that you think that two of them should get numbered. That's a misunderstanding of the job `autonum` is intended to do. If you want something which does something different, that's another matter.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Ideally, I want `autonum` that works.  On this forum, it's too much to ask for someone to provide me with that.  Given that I only ever label the equations that I reference anyway, I'm ok with a solution that only gives numbers to equations that I label.  (I understand I can manually tag/untag).

Comment: @JPi So why not just use the starred versions?

Comment: @JPi Less typing, though - how can it be more hassle?

Comment: I guess, I wasn't sufficiently clear.  I only put in a `\label` if there's a matching `\cref` somewhere else, in which case the equation needs a number.